# Are there any differences between the versions of Lego City Undercover?

Tags: version-differences, lego-city-undercover

Lego City Undercover recently had a remaster for the new generation of consoles, from previously being a Wii U exclusive.  I have two inter-related questions:

- Is there any new content in the remaster?
- Is there any console-exclusive content in the remaster?  For example, there were a few Nintendo references in the original version; I assume these have been removed from the PS4 and Xbox One versions - have they been left in for the Switch version?

Comment: Thus far, I have found that the items that were previously Super Stars have become Police Shields on PS4 - I'm not sure whether the ? blocks have become the "Rex Graffiti Skullptures" maybe?  The red brick for making Chase wear a Mario hat has been removed.